# Diameter of a Riemannian manifold on $SU(N)$ with almost negative curvature everywhere.

Tags: differential-geometry

Are there any results (papers/books) on this problem? I am working on a finite dimensional Riemannian manifold which has a negative curvature almost everywhere. But I do not know if such kind of curvature can lead to any conclusion of the diameter of this manifold.

My exact problem is a Riemannian manifold defined on $SU(2^n)$, where the metric is defined as follows: If $U(t)$ is a curve in $SU(2^n)$ so that $U'(t)=−iH(t)U(t)$, we can defined a metric at $U(t)$ as $<H(t),H(t)>=(P(H(t)),P(H(t)))+(Q(H(t)),Q(H(t)))$, where P,Q are orthogonal projections of $H(t)$ into two orthogonal subspaces and $(P(H),P(H)),(Q(H),Q(H))$ are inner products on these subspaces. It has been indicated that for some parameters and selections of $(P(H),P(H)),(Q(H),Q(H))$, the manifold show a negative curvature almost everywhere.

Can I claim this manifold does not have a finite diameter? Or any other conclusion? Thanks.

Comment: Any compact Riemannian manifold has finite diameter.

Comment: For me the definition of 'compactness' involves the concept of distance. How to judge such a manifold as 'compact' ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space

Comment: Sorry, could you please show me which definition should I use? Or could you please give me more details? Thanks. Since it seems all the definitions use some kind of concepts of 'distance' or 'size', here the distance should be measured by the Riemannian metric. I am not sure if we have a clear idea here what's the meaning of a 'neighbourhood' if two 'nearby' points (using matrix norm) can in fact be 'far away' by the geodesic distance. Thanks.

Comment: Compactness is a property of a topological space, well defined up to homeomorphism. There is a notion of compactness for metric spaces that agrees with the notion for the underlying topological space. You do not need a metric, though - just a topology. $SU(n)$ is a compact topological space. And any function $X \to \Bbb R$, with $X$ a compact space, is bounded. (In particular, $SU(n) \times SU(n) \to \Bbb R, (x,y) \mapsto d(x,y)$, is bounded.) I guess the point to be made here is that the distance function induced by a Riemannian metric is continuous w/r/t the underlying topology.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you please also show me some references about your statement "Any compact Riemannian manifold has finite diameter"? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Any compact Riemannian manifold has finite diameter. Note that a Riemannian metric on a smooth manifold, which has a topology to start with, so compactness is a notion independent of the metric. $SU(n)$ is compact.

Proof: 1) Given a connected Riemannian manifold, broken geodesics endow one with a metric (in the sense of metric spaces) $d_g$ on $M$. It is a standard theorem that the topology induced by $d_g$ is the same as the underlying topology of the manifold; I don't know a name of this theorem. You can find it in any textbook on Riemannian manifolds. In particular, $d_g: M \times M \to \Bbb R$ is continuous.

2) For some topology: given any compact space $X$ and continuous map $f: X \to Y$, $f(X)$ is compact. In particular, if $Y = \Bbb R$, $f(X)$ is closed and bounded (hence has a maximum element).

3) Putting these together, $d_g: M \times M \to \Bbb R$ has a finite, maximum element in its image - the diameter. In particular this is true for $M = SU(n)$.

(More generally, it's true that a Riemannian manifold is compact if and only if it's complete and of finite diameter. One often proves this in the process of, or as a corollary to, the Hopf-Rinow theorem; again this will be in any Riemannian manifolds book.)

Comment: This is not a complete answer to your question, because I have no idea what one can actually say about the diameter given your assumptions other than, uninterestingly, that it's finite.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. Still I have one question. If I select $P(H)$ as a projection on to the subspace of $PH=I\otimes I ....\otimes O_{k}...\otimes I$, where $I$ is $2\times2$ identity matrix and $O$ is any $2\times2$ unitary matrix. Then for $w_Q\rightarrow\infty$, obviously not every $U \in SU(2^n)$ will be attainable from the identity $I \in SU(2^n)$ since you can not put every $U\in SU(2^n)$ as such a tensor product. So the manifold has no finite diameter. Does the contradiction arises from $w_Q\rightarrow\infty$ so that we result in something strange? Thanks again.